# Can't install QGIS 2.6.0 need SQlite3 on OSX Yosemite

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, sqlite

I need to install QGIS on my mac with 10.10 Yosemite, I have already installed:
- SQLite3_Framework-3.8.7.3
- GDAL_Framework-1.11.1-2
- GSL_Framework-1.16-1
- NumPy-1.8.0-1

but when I launch QGIS.pkg it says it requires SQlite3 framework. Please help me [image]

Comment: Have you done a clean install (including removing old QGIS and __emptying the trash__)?

Comment: I never had QGIS or other similar file etc.. is all clean

Comment: Try to uninstall SQLite then reinstall GDAL then QGIS.

Comment: This is definitely a better topic for the [OSGeo user forums](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Quantum-GIS-f4099105.html).

Comment: Nothing to do... it says it needs the sqlte3.framework but I have installed it twice and it is in the folder /Library/Frameworks/

Comment: Have you posted this on the QGIS  user forum? The mac QGIS maintainer is active there and he or others are likely to help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You need to install the SQLite3 framework available here:
http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks
I'm guessing that the version of the framework you have is old or that it's not symlinked properly but the installer available on kyngchaos website should fix it.